# apache camel unit test mock sideffect

Tags: java, junit, apache-camel

I have the following Code similiart to an example from the Book `Camel in Action` in the class `FirstMockTest`:

```
String msg1 = "Camel Msg1";
String msg2 = "Camel Msg2";
String msg3 = "Camel Msg3";
String msg4 = "Camel Msg4";

@Override
protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {
    return new RouteBuilder() {
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            from("jms:topic:quote").to("mock:quote");
            from("jms:topic:quote2").to("mock:quote2");
        }
    };
}
@Override
protected CamelContext createCamelContext() throws Exception {
    CamelContext context = super.createCamelContext();
    //fake jms register
    context.addComponent("jms", context.getComponent("seda"));
    return context;
}


@Test
public void testMultipleBodies() throws InterruptedException {
    MockEndpoint quote = getMockEndpoint("mock:quote");
    template.sendBody("jms:topic:quote", msg1);
    template.sendBody("jms:topic:quote", msg2);
    quote.expectedBodiesReceived(msg1, msg2);
    quote.assertIsSatisfied();
}
@Test
public void testMultipleBodies2() throws InterruptedException {
    MockEndpoint quote2 = getMockEndpoint("mock:quote2");
    template.sendBody("jms:topic:quote2", msg3);
    template.sendBody("jms:topic:quote2", msg4);
    quote2.expectedBodiesReceived(msg3, msg4);
    quote2.assertIsSatisfied();
}
```

When running `gradle clean test --tests FirstMockTest` I get the following 
Unit Test Error Output:

```
 FirstMockTest > testMultipleBodies2 FAILED
    java.lang.AssertionError: mock://quote2 Body of message: 0. 
Expected: <Camel Msg3> but was: <Camel Msg4>
```

Deleting testMultipleBodies makes the test not fail
and changing the template.sendBody commands give 
   `....Expected: <Camel Msg4> but was: <null>`

so it seems that the two routes in configure are not seperated?

Versions: 
apache-camel: 2.5.0
Junit: 4.11

Answer (score 0):

The two JMS routes can process concurrently and therefore depending on CPU timing etc the messages can arrive in different order to the mock endpoint.

So it should be changed from

```
quote2.expectedBodiesReceived(msg3, msg4);
```

To

```
quote2.expectedBodiesReceivedInAnyOrder(msg3, msg4);
```

Comment: No I had the same Problems with `expectedBodiesReceivedInAnyOrder`. (this problem occured because I tried to add an `InAnyOrder` unit Test to an exisiting one.) Also this does not explain why it never fails with only one testMultipleBodies.